# Adjust parents height to fit relative child

Tags: css, less

When in work earlier today I ran into a problem that I'll encounter tomorrow morning, so trying to prepare myself!

Essentially,

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="element-1"></div>
    <div class="element-2"> <img> </div>
</div>
```

both elements are displayed side by side with equal with, and are inline block divs.

element 2 has a position of relative and i've positioned it so it's half within holder and half out of it, using top: 200px.

However, at the moment holder is the height of its largest child, which is element 2 - but it's not taken into account that element-2 has been positioned 200pxs from it's original state, leaving lots of spare space at the bottom of holder!

Summary: I want holders height to take into account an element has been moved - hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: You should include all of your markup. Describing it in paragraph form is worse than including an image. Which you still shouldn't do in place of actual markup; only to complement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your [codepen](https://codepen.io/nikhil_618/pen/POGrOw) would look something like this from your explanations.

The solution would be to add margin instead of top on the element 2 and vertically align the first element to top so it sticks to the top border.

```
.element-2 { 
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.element-1 {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: however, if you wanted element-2 to be positioned at the top of the holder but with half overflowing out, you couldn't use margin-top